# How I can add button to the variants tab in the products screen in Odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-16

I try to add a button in the products screen but I can't find the correct path, and I do not know the problem.

this is my code

```
        <xpath expr="//page[@name='variants']" position="inside">
            <button string="Custom Button" type="object" name="custom_button_method"/>
        </xpath>
```

==========================================

but it gives an error

```
Element '<xpath expr="//page[@name=&#39;variants&#39;]">' cannot be located in parent view
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inherit from the view that adds the variant page to force Odoo to resolve the parent view before applying the `xpath`.

***Example:***

```xml
<record id="product_template_form_extend" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">product.template.form.extend</field>
    <field name="model">product.template</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_only_form_view"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//page[@name='variants']" position="inside">
            <button string="Custom Button" type="object" name="custom_button_method"/>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: this the different 
you use this model ref="product.product_template_only_form_view"
but I am using ref="product.product_template_form_view"
so this is the probelm 
thank you for your effort 
now it working